# ¿ Como hago para que la propiedad agregada se mantenga?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

espero alguien me pueda ayudar con esta duda, tengo el código de la imagen, estoy haciendo una API en Node, lo que hace este servicio es que con un solo endpoint, inserta diferentes cosas en 3 diferentes tablas, prácticamente todas funcionan muy bien, solamente tengo un problema, como ven estoy llamando al método forEach, para que en cada vuelta, valide ciertas cosas, como si el producto existe o no existe, toda esa lógica trabaja perfectamente, el problema viene en la linea 76 y en la linea 85, cada "item" debería tener una propiedad llamada productId, es por eso que la inserto, como ven, hay un console.log() en la linea 88, el cual esta fuera de este bucle, y no se muestra la propiedad productId, pero si muevo ese mismo console.log dentro del bucle, la propiedad si esta, a que se debe esto? y como puedo hacer que la propiedad se agregue y no se quite, ya que la necesito para hacer la inserción a la bd[image]

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: El codigo no debe ir en imagenes para eso hay snippets que permiten agregar fragmentos de codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es debido al forEach de la línea 61. La forma de trabajar funciones asíncronas con el forEach es distinta. Te sugiero cambiarla por un ciclo for(). Puedes ver más información en: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Responder sólo con un enlace se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer]. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Justo era eso, te agradezco mucho la información, lo tomare en cuenta cuando suceda algo por el estilo